# webpack-dev-server not loading html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, webpack

I am trying to use webpack dev server to automatically refresh the browser when I make changes to HTML, and css files. However I'm running into a weird issue shown below when I open localhost:3000 website.

[image]

I can click on the `home-page.html` file and it will load the file however when I make changes to the HTML file or the css file nothing happens. Infact the css that was once applied to the `home-page.html` file is no longer being applied.

I should mention that when I drag the home-page.html file to the browser everything loads properly including the css.

I haven't run into this issue before. I will have multiple HTML files in the future and they will all be located in the `views` directory.

All css files will be located in the `public` directory.

**Below is an image of my working directory**:

[image]

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path')
const postCSSPlugins = [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('autoprefixer')
]

module.exports = {
    entry: './public/scripts/App.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundled.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    devServer: {
        before: function(app, server) {
            server._watch('./views/**/*.html')
        },
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './views'),
        hot: true,
        port: 3000
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader?url=false', {loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {plugins: postCSSPlugins}}]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

Not sure what the issue is. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The reason it wasn't generating the HTML is because the file needs to be named index.html.